# Select element using an id with increasing number jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I created a multiple toggle for a number of links in the same page. They are all closed (with a plus sign) and on click each of them will open a div (and will show a minus sign).

I could get the toggle to work but I'm stuck with the plus and minus signs. 
When one link is open all the links will show the minus sign.

Each `a` has an id with a number from `1` to `15`.

How do we get only the one opened to show the minus sign and all the others the plus sign?

Please advice

**Here the code used:**

```
$('.questions a').removeClass('DownArrow');
$('.questions a').addClass('RightArrow');  

function toggleDiv(divId) {
    $("#"+divId).toggle();
    $('.questions a').toggleClass('DownArrow');
    $('.questions a').toggleClass('RightArrow');
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class='questions'> 
    <a class="DownArrow" id="numb-1" href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent1');">text</a>
</div>
<div id="myContent1">
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
<div class='questions'> 
    <a class="DownArrow" id="numb-2" href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent2');">text</a>
</div>
<div id="myContent2">
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

**Here the CSS:**

```
div#questions  a {  
    display:block; border:1px solid #F00; width:500px; padding:10px; 
}

div#myContent1,div#myContent2,div#myContent3,div#myContent4,div#myContent5 {
    display:none;
}

a.DownArrow {
    background:#ccc url(../images/plus.png) no-repeat 460px 8px;
}

a.RightArrow {
    background:#ccc url(../images/minus.png) no-repeat 460px 8px;
}
```

Comment: *Anytime* you see something like `myAwesomeThing#++` hardcoded in your code, just know you've got some refactoring to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a lot easier if you use evnet handlers instead of inline onclick assignments...
You can just use  the `href` on the acnchors to target:

**Revised Markup**

```
<div class='questions'> 
  <a class="DownArrow" id="numb-1" href="#myContent1">text</a>
</div>
<div id="myContent1">
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
<div class='questions'> 
  <a class="DownArrow" id="numb-2" href="#myContent2">text</a>
</div>
<div id="myContent2">
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function (){
   $('div.questions a').click(function (e){
        var $a = $(this),
            target = $a.attr('href');

        // toggle the classes on the a clicked
        $a.toggleClass('DownArrow RightArrow');

        $(target).toggle(); // show the DIV  
   });
});
```

[Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PHJpZ/)

Comment: I had a similar thought, only in the situation the related `.content` is `$.next()` to the `.question`.

Comment: @Jared: Yeah i try to stay away from depending on traversal because often times things change. The only thing i like to depend upon structure for is context. +1 on your answer though you totally went the extra mile haha

Answer (score 1):

This is a little different than what you've shown, but stick with me here.

If the content opens like an [accordion/collapsing content list](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse) style configuration, you actually don't need all of the cruft with `id`s and whatnot. That's the wonder of jQuery: It puts traversals right at your fingertips.

So this is actually really easy:

```
<div class="questions">
    <span>+</span>
    <a href="#">text</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
<div class='questions'> 
    <span>+</span>
    <a href="#">text</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Note, I'm not demonstrating all of the crazy `id`s, and I've implemented a `content` class. In my examples I'm using a `<span>+</span>` instead of an image for the toggle arrows, too, but that's just because I didn't think it was necessary to demonstrate that. Let me know if you want me to explain that.

The only relevant part of the CSS:

```
.content {
    display: none;
}
```

And here we have the (very, very simple) jQuery:

```
jQuery(function load(){
    var $questions = $('.questions'),
        $content = $('.content');

    $questions.on('click', function toggle(){
        var $this = $(this),
            $selected = $this.next('.content');

        $content.not($selected).hide();

        $selected.show();

        $questions.not(this).find('span').text('+');
        $this.find('span').text('-');

        return false;
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/5t2Un/

So what I've done is...

```
// jQuery(); is a shortcut to $(document).ready()
jQuery(function load(){
    // I'm going to cache my elements for later.
    // I can also use $() inside this function.
    var $questions = $('.questions'),
        $content = $('.content');

    // Here I'm going to detect a click on a `div.questions`,
    // and use this as my toggle.
    $questions.on('click', function toggle(){
        var $this = $(this),
            // Notice I'm using `$.next('.content'). This is
            // how I select the appropriate `.content` for the
            // question.
            $selected = $this.next('.content');

        // Hide all content but what was selected by $.next()
        $content.not($selected).hide();

        // Now show the $this.next('.content'), which we've
        // saved a reference to $selected.
        $selected.show();

        // Toggling the + and -. You can do an $.addClass()
        // and $.removeClass() on the element here.
        $questions.not(this).find('span').text('+');
        $this.find('span').text('-');

        // Return false in case an ANCHOR was clicked, which 
        // will cancel any navigation.
        return false;
    });
});​
```

**EDIT**

Now, if the `.questions` aren't `$.next()` to their related `.content` (and traversal is counter-productive), you can also use a reference within some part of the element. Prodigitalson demonstrated using `href="#myContent1"`, which he fed to jQuery like `$(this.href)` to select the current `.content` by `id`.

I'll demonstrate another method, using the `data-` format.

```
<div class="container nav-bar">
    <div class="questions" data-content-id="#myContent1">
        <span>+</span>
        <a href="#">text</a>
    </div>
    <div class='questions' data-content-id="#myContent2"> 
        <span>+</span>
        <a href="#">text</a>
    </div>
    <div class='questions' data-content-id="#myContent3"> 
        <span>+</span>
        <a href="#">text</a>
    </div>
    <div class='questions' data-content-id="#myContent4"> 
        <span>+</span>
        <a href="#">text</a>
    </div>
    <div class='questions' data-content-id="#myContent5"> 
        <span>+</span>
        <a href="#">text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice this part:

```
<div class="questions" data-content-id="#myContent1">
```

Now I'll use that utilizing `$.data()`:

```
$(function load() {
    var $questions = $('.questions'),
        $content = $('.content');

    $questions.on('click', function toggle() {
        var $this = $(this),
            $selected = $($this.data('content-id'));

        $content.not($selected).hide();
        $selected.show();

        $questions.not(this).find('span').text('+');
        $this.find('span').text('-');

        return false;
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/VCnQn/

This is essentially the same method as I showed previously, except:

```
$selected = $($this.data('content-id'));
```

Which is how we make the association between `.questions` and `.content`. Easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
var id=0;
while(condition){
    $("#myContent"+id).toggle();
    $('.questions a').toggleClass('DownArrow');
    $('.questions a').toggleClass('RightArrow');
    id++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('questions a').each(function(){
 $(this).click(function () {
   var clicked_id = $(this).attr('id');
    //*****
    $('questions a').each(function(){ 
     if ($(this).attr('id') == clicked_id ) {$(this).attr('class', 'class_with_sign_-'); }
     else {$(this).attr('class', 'class_with_sign_+');}
     });
    //*****
 });
});
```

Comment: the `.each()` here is unnecessary -- you can just do `$('.questions a').click(...)`. Also, your answer uses `questions` and should use `.questions`.

Comment: yes I forgot .questions, but the .each() is necessary because $(.question) takes into account only the first element

Comment: I'm still not clear why the outer `.each()` is required -- simply doing `$('.questions a').click(...)` would bind the click to all elements that match the `$('.questions a')` selection, not just to the first one. Furthermore, what you're doing here could be accomplished using `.siblings()`, and the second `.each()` could be avoided as well.